# Is the Windows directory a place for temporary files - GetTempPath function

Tags: c, winapi, temporary-files

I am creating a small library in C, for Windows only, to help me when I want to create an application.
I came across the topic of creating temp files.
I looked at the GetTempPath function documentation and I saw that it uses the first existing environment variable in this order:

1. The path specified by the `TMP` environment variable.
2. The path specified by the `TEMP` environment variable.
3. The path specified by the `USERPROFILE` environment variable.
4. The Windows directory.

The question is: if for some reason the first three variables don't exist and the function returns the Windows directory `C:\Windows\`, is this directory a place to put temporary files?

If it is not then why does the function return it?

**EDIT:** then where should I put the temporary files?

I don't want throw `Access Denied Error` or `Temp Path Not Found Error`

Comment: If you are running on a system that doesn't have those environment variables set, you are running in an unknown environment. The best you can do is to terminate the process. If you try to access `%SystemRoot%\Temp` from a non-admin user account, it will fail anyway, and nothing is gained. You might as well bail out as early as possible. So why does `GetTempPath` return a useless location in the first place? Compatibility with previous versions of Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable Im using `Windows 8.1` also it happened to me that the function returns the Windows directory when I run my program using Cygwin Terminal. I checked the function `GetEnvironmentStrings` all these variables weren't defined even though I set these variable manually in the terminal. that why I asked what I should do

Comment: The solution is simple: Don't run your application from a Cygwin terminal. In addition consider filing a bugreport with the Cygwin team. My suggestion to terminate your process if you run inside an unexpected environment remains valid.

Comment: Out of curiousity, does it really return `C:\Windows` or is it `C:\Windows\TEMP` ?

Comment: If you really *must* support Cygwin (yuck!) perhaps there is a way you could detect the Cygwin environment and use *its* temporary directory?  For example, does Cygwin set any environment variables of its own?

Answer (score 2):

> C:\Windows\, is this directory a place to put temporary files?

Definitly it is not. (This assumes `C:\Windows\` is the Windows Directory as returned by `GetWindowsDirectory ()`).

Also on any recent Windows installation normal users won't even be able to write anything to the Windows Directory (e.g. `C:\Windows\`).

If none of the above three env/ var/s is set let your application create its own directory for temporary files, that is typically located somewhere in the user's home directory.

If your application investigates on this during installation it might consider setting `TMP` or `TEMP` to a reasonable directory and create the latter.

Comment: Yeah - there are shell API calls to find out where to put stuff.

Comment: Maybe it is returned as a last resort because the OS is *sure* that folder exists  So should we use `GetWindowsDirectory` and compare the returned path against this?

Comment: @alk if I always build the path myself like: `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData,0,0,buffer);strcat(buffer,"\\temp\\");`, is it OK?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In which which particular way does putting a user's (temporary) data somewhere in/under the user's home-dir disrespect the user, please?

Comment: @alk because the user has specified where temp data should go through the environment vars and apps should respect that preference

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The question referred to the case where **no** temp-path had been specified: "*if for some reason the first three variables don't exist ...*"

Comment: @alk the comment I responded to starts "if I always build the path myself". Your answer doesn't propose that. In any case I would still just use GetTempPath. It's up to the user to configure a temp path. That should be a per app setting.

Answer (score 1):

This post may not answer the question, but it can explain what is going on and how to fix potential problems:

---

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx) says that `GetTempPath` evaluates a number of environment variables.

However, the Cygwin documentation says that the environment is stripped away from the process. A Cygwin process will therefore not have the necessary environment variables in its context. Conclusively, `GetTempPath` cannot catch them and defaults to the Windows directory.

Solution: There is a function which syncronizes the environment of your process with the surrounding Windows environment:

```
#include <sys/cygwin.h>
...
cygwin_internal (CW_SYNC_WINENV);
```

See the [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-env.html) documentation.